# Activity iCal : Start time = End time

Tags: civimail, activities

I work with CiviCRM 4.6 and Drupal 4.7
When I create an activity in CiviCRM, a iCal file is also created and sent. But in this iCal file, Start time = End time. So when I import the file in my calendar the activity doesn't have the right duration. Any idea ? Maybe I can modify a template, but how ?
Regards,
Hashkey

Comment: did you set a duration in the activity?

Comment: As a side-note, are you really using Drupal 4.7? That version has not been supported for a very long time.

Comment: Hello John,Sorry it's Drupal 7.36.

Answer (score 1):

Check:

templates/CRM/Activity/Calendar/ICal.tpl

I just took a quick look there and seems like the duration is not taken into account at all, which is a bug :(

Can you take a look and see if you can fix it. If so, please do submit a PR against the CiviCRM github repo. I'm pretty sure the activity object will be sending in the duration field. You should also file an issue for this on the CiviCRM issue tracker

Comment: For completeness, here's the issue on the tracker: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15703